# Is there a way to only download the login.vue page of a client-side application until the user authenticates?

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

I am developing a Nuxtjs 3.x web app. And I am wondering if it is possible to hide any sensitive front-end code from unauthenticated users.

For instance, an unauthenticated user would load the website in a browser and that browser would receive only the code required to render the login.vue page. Once the user successfully authenticates the browser would then receive the rest of the application (e.g. Dashboard.vue, etc.vue) and get redirected off wherever into the app they desire.

Comment: [middleware](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware) is what you looking for

Comment: I have a basic auth middleware I made to check if the user has a JWT and redirect them to the login page, but that doesn't stop the whole app from being downloaded. Can you give me any more information about how I might use middleware to do this?

Comment: Even if you have the shell of the secure page (like dashboard), the server will not send the sensitive parts that makes the dashboard interesting. Also, you'll have lazy loading of the routes, so until you visit it you will not download it. And if you do, then it will be empty and you'll be middleware redirected.

Comment: @kissu So the unauthenticated user gets sent to the login page and their browser receives some static js files from the webserver, (planning using the static rendering method vs SSR). I was under the impression that those static js files include all the sensitive bits, is that not the case?

Comment: If your auth system is doing things well, he will by default remove those sensitive parts (overall lead to a blank page) if not-authenticated. This is how the nuxt module for auth worked with Nuxt2 at least but if the solution you're planning to use nowadays doesn't, make a quick `v-if` on the whole page to check if people are authenticated or not. By default, should be set to false so that even if JS is disabled, no sensitive content leaks.